# Рамки между элементами меню (списка)

Tags: html, css

Ребят нужна помощь, как сделать так что бы рамки шли по центру между слов как показано на скриншоте:

[image: Вот так]

Answer (score 1):

Это просто border вот [пример](https://jsfiddle.net/8npysxqo/)

```css
li {
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
li:last-child {
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
ul{
  background:#4d99e2;
  padding:5px 0;
  font-size:0;
}
ul li{
  list-style-type:none;
  display:inline-block;
}
ul li a{
  font-size:14px;
  color:#fff;
  padding:0 10px;
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
}
ul li a::after{
  content:"";
  width:1px;
  height:100%;
  background:#fff;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
}
ul li:last-child a::after{
  background:0 none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#!">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#!">Checkout</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#!">Log In</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Как то так))

Comment: можно подсократить - `ul li:not(:last-child) a:after`

Comment: В принципе да, согласен